# unable to remove space between the stepconnector and StepIcon in material-ui stepper

Tags: css, material-ui

Hi My Objective is to not to give space between the step and connector. i've tried everyway but still i couldn't figure out.

By Default we're getting the space in between the step icon and connector. but i don't want to show space in between them.

I tried to give margin and all but still i couldn't remove space between the connector and step icon.

Here is my sample code:

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "90%"
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  actionsContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  },
  resetContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  contentRoot: {
    borderColor: "red"
  },
  connectorLine: {
    borderColor: "red"
  }
});
```

````
 <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper
          connector={
            <StepConnector
              classes={{
                line: classes.connectorLine
              }}
            />
          }
          activeStep={activeStep}
          orientation="vertical"
        >
          {steps.map((label, index) => {
            return (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                <StepContent
                  classes={{
                    root: classes.contentRoot
                  }}
                >
                  <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
                  <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                    <div>
                      <Button
                        disabled={activeStep === 0}
                        onClick={this.handleBack}
                        className={classes.button}
                      >
                        Back
                      </Button>
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={this.handleNext}
                        className={classes.button}
                      >
                        {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </StepContent>
              </Step>
            );
          })}
        </Stepper>
        {activeStep === steps.length && (
          <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
            <Typography>All steps completed - you&quot;re finished</Typography>
            <Button onClick={this.handleReset} className={classes.button}>
              Reset
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </div>
```

[here is sample o/p](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-r4pe2?file=/demo.js:2300-4152).


Can anyone help me with this query?
Thanks! in advance
````

Comment: Without digging in to deep this is probably CSS related - please include the CSS you have that is directly related to your issue (try to reproduce the issue IN your question if possible)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Hi, you're correct - it's a CSS issue. I'll update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `alternativeLabel` in `StepConnector` component. To achieve this goal, create a new Customized `StepConnector` e.g. called `CustomizedConnector` as below and then override the alternativeLabel to reduce the gap between connector and icon:

```
const CustomizedConnector = withStyles({
  // this attribute will reduce the gap. change 7px to whatever value that fit your design
  alternativeLabel: {
    top: 10,
    left: "calc(-50% + 7px)",
    right: "calc(50% + 7px)"
  },
  
   /* other style attributes */
   /* other style attributes */
   /* other style attributes */


})(StepConnector);
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6bnlb?file=/demo.js)